# Class variable: public access read-only, but private access r/w

Tags: java, class-variables

In my current project I have a class which stores its Instance in a variable. This Instance should be accesible by all other classes in the project, but it may only be altered by its own class.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with "its instance"? Is there only one instance of the class? (A singleton)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Write a `public` getter but *no* `public` setter. And the field itself `private`

Comment: And the field's type must be immutable.

Comment: If the field's type is not immutable you can always return a deep copy of it instead of a reference to itself to ensure that the field could not be modified by others.

Answer (score 4):

In short that is called `immutable object`,  state of `Object` cannot change after it is constructed.

`String` is a common example of immutable `Class`.

Make a `class` `immutable` by following-

- ensure the class cannot be `overridden` - make the `class` `final`, or use
  `static` factories and keep constructors private.
- make fields `private` and `final`
- force callers to construct an object completely in a single step,
  instead of using a `no-argument constructor` combined with subsequent
  calls to `setXXX` methods.
- do not provide any methods which can change the state of the object
  in any way - not just `setXXX` methods, but any method which can change
  state
- if the class has any mutable object fields, then they must be
  defensively copied when passed between the class and its caller.

Answer (score 2):

Someone suggests "public getter but no public setter for the private field."

Caution:  This would only work if the field is primitive type.
If it is an object with setters, the content can still be modified; thus not read-only.

It will be interesting to see Java language provide some constructs to make a return type read-only without having to do a deep-copy / clone.

i'm imaging like
ReadOnly getEmployee() {
  ...}

Answer (score 0):

The boilerplate code for instantiating a singleton can be found in many places, see for example http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/designpatterns/index.html

Be aware that many consider the singleton to be an antipattern because it's pretty hard to get rid of once your application is littered with references to the singleton.