# Java: Variable access specifiers

Tags: java, class, variables, private, public

In java, is there a (direct) way to make a variable able to be accessed out of the class but not able to be changed? I have a variable in class A and need it in class B. I can make it public (bad-practice) but i don't want class B to be able to change it. Is there a way to do this or will I just have to make it public and be careful? Also I need to maintain the ability to change the variable from within Class A, ruling out final.

Comment: Please refer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324805/class-variable-public-access-read-only-but-private-access-r-w

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151342/do-we-have-a-readonly-field-in-java-which-is-set-able-within-the-scope-of-the-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324805/class-variable-public-access-read-only-but-private-access-r-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: you can provide a getter.  That's pretty much it, but that's how you're *supposed* to do it.

```
public Type getField() {
  return field;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that counts as "direct" though

Comment: @BenjaminLowry it's the closest thing in the Java language to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

you can use reflection to read the private values.

public class Test1 {

```
private int num;
public Test1(int n){
    this.num =n;
}
```

}

Accessing private variable

```
Field classField = Test1.class.
            getDeclaredField("num");
    classField.setAccessible(true);
    classField.getInt(t);
    System.out.println(classField.getInt(t));
```